# Facebook notification drop-down by angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller

i'm trying to make notification drop-down like facebook , when the notification is unread the there's a status that's unread is true or false so i want to make the background color of this notification gray else unread is unread =false so the back ground is white. and there is a bubble when i click it make the unread notification as read !

```
<li ng-if="vm.logged">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn-noti" id="dropdownNoti" ng-click="vm.showDropdown($event)">
              <span class="fa fa-bell-o"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownNoti">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="border-bottom: #655771;border-bottom-style: double;">
                <h5 class="notification-title"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> Notifications</h5>
                <a class="mark-all" ng-click="vm.markAllRead()">Mark all as read</a>
              </div>
              <li ng-if="!vm.notifications.length"><a>You have no new notification yet.</a></li>
              <li class="notification-type"  ng-repeat="notification in vm.notifications" ng-if="notification.unread==true" ng-style="{'color':'red'}" style="border-bottom-style: ridge;">
                <a href="">{{notification.description}}
                  <h6><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{vm.timeOf(notification)}}</h6>
                </a>
                <a class="mark-as btn btn-default " ng-click="vm.markAsRead(notification.id)"></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ng-class` to test the expression and add a specific class with `background-color` propety

```
ng-class="$variableToEvaluate ? 'class-if-true' : 'class-if-false'">
```

Comment: i used that ng-style="{'background-color': notification.unread==false? 'white' : '#f5f5f5'}" and it worked ^^